# Expected number of connections between different colour nodes in a network with variable connectivity

Tags: connections, random-graphs, network

## Background

There is a network of $N$ nodes.

Each node has a colour: Red; Green or Blue (in a more general form they may be additional colours, but there is at least one other colour that Red and Green)

Colours have been randomly assigned to nodes.

Each node has a number of connections (also known as a [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) of connectitivity), $k$ to distinct other nodes.
Every node has at least 1 connection and no node has more than $n$ connections. (i.e. there are no isolated vertexes. $\Delta\left(G\right)=n$ and $\delta\left(G\right)=1$ to use the notation from [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)).)

The connectivity number of each node was randomly assigned independently from the colour assignment.

There is no concept of direction of a connection in this network.

## Given

We know the distribution function for connectivity number ignoring colours:

$$
N=\sum^{n}_{k=1}N_k
$$

We know the number of Red nodes, $N^R$ and the numbers of them as a function of their connectivity:

$$
N^R=\sum^{n}_{k=1}N^R_k
$$

Also for Green nodes:

$$
N^G=\sum^{n}_{k=1}N^G_k
$$

The distributions for other colours is knowable if necessary for solving the problem, but I believe it is not required.

## Problem

Over all possible networks with the specified values of $N_k$, $N^R_k$, $N^G_k$ and $n$ for $1\le k \le n$.

If a Red node of connectivity $k$ is chosen at random, what is the probability that $j$ of those connections are to Green nodes (irrespective of the Green node connectivity)

Alternatively,

What is the expected number of the $N^R_k$ Red nodes with connectivity $k$ that have exactly $j$ connections to Green nodes ($1\le j\le k$)

## Attempt 1 (2021-09-10)

NOTE: I will consider an acceptable answer if you can show this attempt to be correct.

NOTE: I believe this attempt to be incorrect!

Because each connection is to a distinct node, from the context of a randomly selected red node of degree $k$, it has selected $k$ other nodes from the remaining $N-1$.

The contingency table should look like this:

|  | connected | not connected | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| green nodes | $j$ | $N^G-j$ | $N^G$ |
| not green | $k-j$ | $N-1-N^G-k+j$ | $N-1-N^G$ |
| total | $k$ | $N-1-k$ | $N-1$ |

The probability of having exactly $j$ connections to a green node then comes from the hypergeometric distribution

$$
P(\text{\(j\) green connections}|\text{red node of degree \(k\)})=\frac{{{N^G}\choose{j}} {{N-1-N^G}\choose{k-j}}}{{{N-1}\choose{k}}}
$$

We know the probability of a red node with degree $k$:

$$
P(\text{red node of degree \(k\)})=\frac{N^R}{N}
$$

So the probability that a node selected at random is a red node of degree $k$ with $j$ connections to green nodes is then:

$$
P(\text{red node of degree \(k\) with \(j\) green connections}) = P(\text{red node of degree \(k\)})P(\text{\(j\) green connections}|\text{red node of degree \(k\)}) = \frac{N^R}{N}\frac{{{N^G}\choose{j}} {{N-1-N^G}\choose{k-j}}}{{{N-1}\choose{k}}}
$$

And thus in a network of $N$ nodes the expected number of red nodes of degree $k$ with exactly $j$ connections to green nodes is given by:

$$
{N^R}\frac{{{N^G}\choose{j}} {{N-1-N^G}\choose{k-j}}}{{{N-1}\choose{k}}}
$$

Where $1\le j \le k \le n$ and $N^G \ge j$

## Attempt 1 is wrong (2021-09-12)

Consider $N=100$, $N^R=N^R_1=1$ and $N^G=N^G_{99}=1$ here the expected number of red balls of degree 1 with 1 connection to a green ball is, by construction, 1, but my attempt gives a number less than 1.

Thus my attempt 1 cannot be correct

Comment: Does "connectivity" mean the same thing as [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory))?

Comment: If you have a solution for the case where all connections of any node are not forced to be to distinct nodes, ie if node A has 3 connections but say two of those are to the same node, that would be nice to know as it should be approximately the same for large $N$ but this question is for the case where A’s 3 connections are always to 3 distinct nodes.

Comment: Yes, I was searching for the correct term. Do you think it would improve the question to change it to “degree”?

Comment: Is the probability distribution uniform over the collection of graphs that satisfy the specified values of $N_k, N_k^R, N_k^G$? (i.e. is each valid graph equiprobable?) Just trying to understand what the probability distribution being considered is. There seems to be two sources of randomness: the choice of graph, and the choice of the red node.

Comment: Good question. Let’s assume they are equally likely. I can probably extend the approach to non-uniform probabilities once I understand the simpler answer (if that’s necessary)

Comment: One approach I have been considering is to leverage that connections are distinct, so there are $N-1$ ways the first connection can be selected and $N^G$ of them are green. $N-2$ ways to pick the second, etc. I.e. it’s just standard picking $k$ balls from a bag of $N-1$ balls and getting the probability that $j$ if them are green. But this feels too easy a solution and I think I am making a mistake