# Counting undirected simple connected graphs with a specific degree distribution

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Context: I am trying to find a solution to [a more complex problem involving coloured undirected simple graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246230/expected-number-of-connections-between-different-colour-nodes-in-a-network-with)

Given a simple undirected connected graph, $G=(V, E)$

The number of vertices, $N$, is given by the cardinality of the set of vertices

$$N=\left|V\right|$$

We can compute the adjacency matrix for this graph, $a_{ij}$, using the following rule:

$$
a_{ij}=\left\{
\begin{matrix}
0 && \left\{\left\{i,j\right\},\left\{j,i\right\}\right\} \cap E = \emptyset\\
1 && \left\{\left\{i,j\right\},\left\{j,i\right\}\right\} \cap E \ne \emptyset
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

Note: this matrix is symmetric by construction (well known property of undirected graph) and the diagonal elements are all 0 (well known property of simple graphs). Also every row and column has at least one 1 as the graph is connected (i.e. every node has at least one connection)

For vertex, $i$, we can compute the degree of the vertext, $deg(i)$ as the sum of either row $i$ or column $i$ of the adjacency matrix

$$
deg(i) = \sum_j a_{ij} = \sum_j a_{ji}
$$

Let $D_k$ be the set of all vertices of degree $k$.

$$
D_k=\left\{i : deg(i)=k \land i \in V \right\}
$$

We can then define the number of vertexes of cardinality $k$ as

$$
N_k=\left|D_k\right|
$$

It follows that as $V=D_1\cup D_2 \cup...\cup D_m$ where $m$ is the maximum degree of the graph

$$
N = \sum_k D_k
$$

Given $N$ and $N_1,N_2,...,N_m$ how many possible graphs $G$ can be constructed with that specified cardinality of degrees?

Comment: What kind of answer to your question do you expect?

Comment: A double sum over $N_1,…N_m$ probably with some binomial coefficients. Or a DOI link. But essentially any function of the $m$ variables that define the cardinality

Comment: I don’t know if there is an answer. My intuition says there should be something like $\sum\sum{x\choose y}{z\choose w}$ with perhaps a $\frac{1}{2}$ or something like that

Comment: Take, for example, the sequence $(N_1,N_2,N_3)=(0,0,N)$. How many such graphs do you think can be constructed? Even in this simplest case there are no general formulas and in my opinion even estimates. See, for example, [here](https://oeis.org/A002851).

Comment: https://mathinsight.org/generating_networks_desired_degree_distribution describes a configuration model for construction of a network with a given structure but that model doesn’t guarantee that the resulting network will be simple or connected, you have to subtract them out when generating. Not sure if that helps deriving the cardinality of solutions to a given structure

Comment: Well in your example, we know there are $N!$ rearrangements if any solution. We can therefore define a rule to sort the vertexes based on say smallest cycle length and count how many solutions exist under the sorting constraints. For every solution then multiply by $N!$ to get the total cardinality

Comment: Also in your example, I think half of the integers have no solution as there’s a dangling edge